# Is this method of string encrypting "uncrackable"?

Tags: keys, random-number-generator

I was thinking of unique methods of encrypting strings, and I thought of this.

Given a string, for example "Hello, World!" we can convert it into a char array using a computer program, and then convert each char into the corresponding number from the ASCII charcode table. (For example, H is 72, e is 101 etc.) then multiply each number by a random "key", which is just an integer (which will be the same for each number), in this case lets say it is 3042 (So 72 is now 219024, 101 is now 307242).

Then, remove from each number a value, which will be our second key (In this case, lets say it's 287), So 219024 becomes 218737 etc.

Now you see, if 2nd key wasn't removed from the result of the number * key1, then we could simply find the common factors of all the numbers, and grab the key.

However since a second key is removed, is this method of encryption *practically uncrackable* without knowing at least the 2nd key?

Comment: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break. Use well vetted methods such as AES, take a look at how [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) is designed. Attackers are quite good at encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is a sightly convoluted version of a [substitution cypher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher).  Every letter in the plaintext is replaced with an integer in the cyphertext.  If I have two 'e's, both will encode to the same value.

Unfortunately, in this case, the algorithm is far from uncrackable. There's a famous phrase, "Anyone can create an encryption algorithm so complicated that even they cannot crack it." This is one of those cases.  All substitution cyphers fall victim to statistical analysis.  If you have any information as to the statistical likelyhood of letters or words, you can rather rapidly deduce the keys.  This kind of cypher was considered unbreakable in the era of Caesar, but since the formalization of probability in the 1600's, this kind of encryption is considered "fully broken."

The fastest approach to break this algorithm is to gather enough characters to be confident that you have two sequential characters (such as an 'a' and a 'b'   or a 'g' and an 'h').  This can be guaranteed in 14 unique characters if you limit yourself to uppercase letters, or 129 characters if you have the entire 8-bit ASCII space at your disposal (the pigeonhole principle guarantees that if you have that many characters, at least one pair of them must be sequential).  Once you have enough characters, simply sort them and find the smallest gap.  The letters with the smallest gap between them are sequential.  Once you have those two, you can do simple algebra to get the two keys.

If you attempt to avoid this hole by only using half of the alphabet (acegikmoprtvxz, for instance), the attacker will see gibberish if they make this attack.  When they realize this, they can simply look at multiples of the key they generated until the messages start making sense.

Comment: I see. However, what if the person trying to crack it, doesn't know the algorithm, or how this encryption method works? He would just see a bunch of numbers that could symbolize anything. How would he know he has to add a secret key, then divide by a different key which would be the greatest common divisor, and then convert the numbers left into letters?

Comment: When cryptographic algorithms are tested, it is assumed the attacker knows the algorithm, in and out.  The only things they don't know are the plaintext and the key (and sometimes they're even permitted to know the plaintext).  An algorithm where the algorithm must remain secret is simply not valued by the cryptographic community.

Comment: That aside, if you wanted a fair assessment of how your algorithm would fare if both the key and the algorithm were secret, we'd have to look at what sort of messages you send.  The classic attack against a substitution cypher is a statistical analysis of the cyphertext.  Given your example of "Hello World," I think it's reasonable to guess your intent was to send English text.  If so, I'd say that if you gave a 100 character message to a mediocre cryptanalyst, it'd take them about 5 minutes to figure out the algorithm and keys.  A good cryptanalyst would get it far faster.

Comment: Honestly, cryptanalysts are good at their job.  A statistical analysis of the cyphertext is one of the first things you'd do against an unknown cypher to try to find a weakness.  It would be immediately obvious that, despite the numbers being large, there's only 20 or so unique numbers. (26 if you manage to use all letters).  I'm wary of overstating how easy this is to crack, because I'd hate to dissuade you from exploring the field of cryptography more by attacking the algorithm too hard, but what you have is literally a case study Casear cypher that is typically broken...

Comment: ... in the first chapter of any book on cryptography to demonstrate just how easy it is to think that your algorithm is invincible, when it is actually trivially breakable.

Comment: Oh alright. I understand. However, I would like to know this:
If I give the numbers to a cryptanalyst, would he be able to crack it and find the algorithm? Because, to me, it looks like numbers. Now I'm not a proffesional, but there's many things someone can think when he sees plain numbers, it could be letters converted straight into numbers, it could be chars converted into numbers and raised to a power, it could be chars converted to numbers, then added a number, hell it could even be that every char has a unique number that is not taken from the charcode number table, how would he know?

Comment: You may want to read about statistical cryptanalysis.  Its a very powerful technique that destroys these kinds of cyphers, and its very easy to implement.  If a professional looked at your numbers, the first thing they'd do would be to plot a histogram of the numbers, and would instantly recognize the frequency distribution of English text.  80% would be decrypted in moments.  Then, once they're confident of that simple substitution cypher, they would look at the numbers and try to see if they can figure out your equation.  In this case, its a linear function, so they'd find it fast.

Comment: For an example of existing cyphers that work like this, I recommend the pigpen cypher: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigpen_cipher .  It's in a similar class in that you'd think that there's no way an adversary could decode the random non-numeric symbols, but in fact statistical crytpanalysis takes care of it rather rapidly.

Comment: Here's the wikipeida page on how to defeat these kinds of cyphers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis

Comment: What if I use for every letter different integer? I mean, if I have very long keytext and I use one letter from it only once. For example, keytext= Tree. If I want to use "e" first time I will write "3", if I want to use "e" second time I write "4" and never use the same integer for the same letter. Is that kind of text crackable?

Comment: @vasili111 Easily crackable.  The exact methodology you would use to crack it would depend on the exact algorithm (hint: if a second "e" is encoded as `4`, then no other letter in the alphabet can be encoded as a `4` in that spot), but you're buying minimal protection.  Perhaps if you were a Roman general sending instructions 3000 years ago, it might have been hard to crack, but we've gotten very good at cracking in the last 3 millennia.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your encryption method:

1. If you analyzed the cypher text for patterns you would easily find repetitive numbers in an encrypted word, corresponding to repetitive letters, hinting therefore to the original word.
2. The same would happen to words in a sentence. Two equal words would produce an equal encryption, thus exposing your cyphered text to statistics analysis.

With a statistical analysis, one would easily find out your original text and deduce the secret keys.

Comment: Brute force would work fine as well, especially if the algorithm is known...

Comment: Only two problems???  You, sir, are being kind...

Comment: @poncho - I'm a newbie in crypto, that's the best I can do at the moment given the analysis time I had.